# python program will not continue

Tags: python

i am writing a program about coin flips i want the user to enter number and for the program to flip a coin that many times.

once the user gives number the program stops

this is what i have

```
import random
flips = 0
heads=0
tails=0
numFlips = raw_input("Flips ")
while flips < numFlips:
    flips += 1
    coin = random.randint(1, 2)
    if coin == 1:
        print('Heads')
        heads+=1
    if coin == 2:
        print ('Tails')
        tails+=1
total = flips
print(total)
print tails
print heads
```

Comment: and your question is? :)

Comment: Please try to follow the style guidelines described in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and keep your code consistent. For example, mixing `print(x)` and `print x` is an incredibly bad idea (you should use whatever is appropriate for your python version, i.e. `print x` for py2 and `print(x)` for py3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numFlips` is a `str`. You have to convert it to an `int` first.

```
numFlips = int(raw_input("Flips "))
```

Otherwise, your check `flips < numFlips` will not work, [since all `int`s are 'less than' any string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int).

(Also, you want to add some error-handling for the case the user enters something other than an integer)

Answer (score -1):

On line

`numFlips = raw_input("Flips ")`

`raw_input()` reads a string : http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Convert it to integer by doing `int(raw_input("Flips "))`

You can also use [input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) evaluates the string to a python expression, which in this case would evaluate to an int.

EDIT: As pointed out by @bruno desthuilliers,  it is unsafe to use input() and should rather just convert the raw_input() to int.

Comment: And that's a _very_ wrong solution. `input` doesn't "evaluates the string to an int", it evaluates the string as a Python expression, whatever it is,  including a call to "os.system('rm -rf /')". `input` is unsafe. Don't use `input`. Do the RightThing and convert the input to what the program expects.

Comment: Note that you could/should use `ast.literal_eval` (instead of `input`/`eval`), which will safely evaluate to strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.